# Reasons for preferring unorder_set to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

what would be reasons for preferring unordered_set to a vector for example?
I've tried to come up with some ideas but I simply cannot imagine why I would won't it. For interface? What else?

Comment: First off, a set doesn't permit duplicates.

Comment: @Harry yes, that's true. But then we have unordered_multiset. What would the reasons be there?

Comment: I would really appreciate explanation for those downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can store non-copyable, non-movable objects in an `unordered_set`.
- Finding whether a given element is in the set is O(1) instead of O(n), or O(log n) if you keep the vector sorted (which is itself O(n) on insertion).
- `unordered_set` disallows duplicates.
- Removing a given element is O(1). In the case of a sorted vector, it's O(n).

Comment: `You can store non-copyable, non-movable objects in an unordered_set.` i take it that you are talking about `emplace()` with this?  If so vector does have `emplace_back()`

Comment: @NathanOliver `emplace_back` won't suffice when the vector needs to resize to accomodate for new elements, or shift said elements to be ordered.

Comment: Okay.  I get that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`unordered_set` allows you to check whether an element belongs to that set in `O(1)` average time. Other standard set operations (insert, remove) are also `O(1)`. So a set (or `unordered_set`) is mainly used when what you need is a mathematical [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)): it is a container (data structure) specifically developed to support standard set operations.

Assume you have some dictionary of words and you want to be able to quickly check whether a given word belongs to this dictionary. Storing the dictionary words in an `unordered_set` will provide you with a much faster solution as compared to storing words in a `vector`.